# When is the LEB128 (u/s) used?

Tags: android, compression, dalvik

In a dex file, for what purpose is the LEB128 used? [This page](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dex-format.html) says it's used 
 *In a .dex file, LEB128 is only ever used to encode 32-bit quantities.*
Are there any other uses of the LEB128?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you refer to is a mirror of the Dalvik docs. FWIW, I maintain a more up-to-date version [here](http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/dex-format.html).

The only Android-specific uses of LEB128 that I'm aware of are in .dex files. In .dex files, the format is used all over the place. You should just refer back to the spec to see, as it's very well documented.